# Do we say "you infected me with your disease" or "you transmitted your disease to me" or other common ways to express the same idea?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

In the dictionary

> **[infect](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/infect?q=infect)** (verb) to make a disease or an illness spread to a person, an animal or a plant
>
> **infect somebody/something** 
>   *It is not possible to infect another person through kissing.*
>
> **infect somebody/something with something** 
>   *people infected with HIV*

---

But we also have the verb "**[transmit](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/transmit?q=transmit)**"

> ​[transitive] (formal) to pass something from one person to another
>   synonym transfer
>
> **transmit something** *sexually transmitted diseases*
>
> **transmit something to somebody** *Parents can unwittingly transmit their own fears to their children.*

---

And the verb **[Spread](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spread_1?q=spread)**

> [intransitive, transitive] to affect or make something affect, be
>   known by, or be used by more and more people
>
> **(+ adv./prep.)** *The disease spreads easily.*
>
> *Within weeks, his confidence had spread throughout the team.*
>
> *Use of computers spread rapidly during that period.*
>
> **spread something** *to spread rumours/lies about somebody*
>
> *The disease is spread by mosquitoes.*

---

So what is the common way to express the idea.

"**you infected me with your disease**"

or "**you transmitted your disease to me**"

or "**you spread your disease to me**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three of your sentences are grammatical in English.

But please note, when the subject of the sentence is "you", it has the tone of an accusation: the transmission of the disease was an action done by "you." It would be more neutral to use the passive voice, or to put yourself (I) as the subject of the sentence.

It is also pretty confrontational to use the expression "*your* illness", or especially "*your* ***disease***", as if the disease is that person's own private property.

If this is the effect you *want* to convey, then your 1st sentence is the most aggressive accusation of the three:

"You infected me with your disease." The spreading of the infection probably wasn't on purpose, but this sentence seems almost to imply that it was deliberate.

More neutral ways of saying the same thing would be:

> "I *caught* the disease/illness/infection from you."
>
> "The disease was spread/transmitted from you to me."

Or, to sound a little more "medical":

> "I *contracted* the disease/illness/etc. from you."